# Lotus notes domino server: updating view process

Tags: lotus-domino

i have a problem with the updating view process(that i can see in the notes log.nsf) because lotus notes server start to updating all view of all database during staff working time and i want that it start for example at 20:00 pm of every day when all user are not working with notes, because Updating xxx.nsf view 'aaa' process reduce a lot server performance and database works slowly).
I cannot find the correct configuration tab in the domino administrator where set the starting time of this process.

In the Sever\status\scheduled\agent tab there are only the lotus notes scheduled agents 
and in the configuration\program tab there are only compact and fixup program(scheduled at 22:00 pm and 01:00 am).

I cannot find the exactly way to set updating view process starting time.
There is someone that can help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the notes.ini of the server: There you will find entries for ServerTasksAtX. X stands for the hour, when these tasks start.

Let the server show all ow them by typing: `show config ServerTasksAt*`
Usually there is a line:

ServerTasksAt1=Updall

If the server starts this task an another time, then this must have been changed, or the timezone of your server is not correct.

Also search for program documents in the nab, that have "updall" as task, but as you stated there are only fixup and compact tasks.

Be aware: If you start a compact with option -D this will discard all indices, so that after completion they have to be rebuild.

Comment: in the server notes.ini there are this 3 row:

Comment: ServerTasks=Replica,Router,Update,AMgr,Adminp,Sched,CalConn,DIIOP,HTTP,smtp
ServerTasksAt1=Catalog
ServerTasksAt2=UpdAll
ServerTasksAt5=Statlog                                               Perfect, now i try to modify that value ! thank's, it was just the reply that i looking for !

Comment: the relevant is "ServerTasksAt2". but if your server is in the wrong timezone, this might start at any time else...

Comment: ok, but the timezone is correct. now i have set it at 23:00 and today evening i restart my server so the changes take effect and we will see. thank's Torsten !